# Issues with Magento 1.9.x and cached images frontend permissions

Tags: cache, permissions

We are trying to get a magento to run on a cpanel server, main issue right now is actually that all the generatet cache images for the front end ends up with 0640 and folders with 0750 this is an issue, is there some sort of way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

change the recursive value of var folder and files by default. Remember Use SSH.

1) chmod -R 644 ./*

2) find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

3) find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;